# fontspec FakeBold affects text in graphics

Tags: xetex, fontspec

In the minimal example below (compiled with XeLaTeX in MacTex), the `FakeBold` option in package `fontspec` works as intended for the main text, using Times to represent the non-default font I am using in my actual document. However, `FakeBold` also thickens the Helvetica font used in the included graphic `plot.pdf` (available from [here](http://people.pwf.cam.ac.uk/yl445/plot.pdf)) although the Helvetica font is not embedded in that PDF.

Furthermore, the Helvetica font is thickened to the same degree regardless of the `FakeBold` setting, i.e. `FakeBold=0.5`, `FakeBold=1`, `FakeBold=3` all produce the same amount of thickening in the Helvetica font. However, if I embed the Helvetica into `plot.pdf`, then `FakeBold` works nicely within the graphic.

There are two issues here:

1. `FakeBold` was invoked only for Times but it affected the Helvetica in the graphic.
2. In the case where Helvetica hadn't been embedded in the graphic, `fontspec` apparently detected the presence of some kind of text in the graphic and applied a thickening that was insensitive to the setting of `FakeBold` for the main text.

I tried to prevent `FakeBold` from thickening the text in the graphic by setting `FakeBold=0` just before the graphic but to no effect. I also tried `\setsansfont[FakeBold=0]{Helvetica}` but of course this had no effect because the text within the graphic wasn't being identified as Helvetica. I have tried other fonts for the main text and within the graphic and the same behaviour arises. There does not appear to be any mention of this in the `fontspec` documentation, and I am incapable of getting into its source code to look for the cause.

I would be very grateful if someone could hint at how I could overcome this problem. I apologise if it's something blindingly obvious.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FakeBold=1]{Times}

\begin{document}

Test test test

\includegraphics{plot.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: @Werner: thanks for the welcome and the correction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure but the last sentence of the second paragraph sounds as if problem goes away if you embed the font in the plot.pdf. Then imho this is the correct way to solve the problem. One should always embed all fonts in a pdf and not rely on external fonts on the system.

But if for some reason you can't embed the font. You can also avoid the problem by selecting *and using* a font without FakeBold before the graphic. A simple dot is enough:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FakeBold=1]{Times New Roman}



\begin{document}

Test test test

\begingroup
\fontspec{Times New Roman}{\color{white}.}
\includegraphics{plot.pdf}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would a `\vphantom{.}` suffice?

Comment: No. But you can move the text "outside view" e.g. with `\raisebox{30cm}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt]{blub}}`. Probably someone who knows the pdf-specification could also insert some pdf-specials to reset the embolden.

Comment: @Ulrike: apologies, I realize that the problem remains when I embed the font and use my original code. I was fooled previously because, with embedding, FakeBold emboldens the graphic text to a _constant_ but _different_ degree than the unembedded case. Your code above does exactly what I want and, unlike the workarounds I tried, can be used within the figure environment and does not break other things. Thanks very much for solving the problem.