# Incompatibility between fontspec and graphicx (bug of XeTeX)

Tags: graphics, xetex, fontspec, incompatibility

I got a weird problem with the [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package and the [`graphicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package. Let's see the MWE first.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\test[AutoFakeBold = 5]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\test
Test
\textbf{Bold Test}

\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{photo}

Words that shouldn't be bolded. Even if \textmd{textmd-ed}.
\end{document}
```

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](https://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/005yyi5Jjw1enwheh2gb8j30um0ietbx.jpg))</sub>

In the preamble, I loaded the `graphicx` package and the `fontspec` package, then I set `Times New Roman` as the default font of the text as well as the font of the `test` command. In the definition of `\test`, I enabled `AutoFakeBold`. In the document body, between the two chains of text, I inserted a photo with the `\includegraphics` command.

It's a normal manuscript, except that `AutoFakeBold` was set to `5` to make the abnormal output more remarkable. After the compilation, however, the later line of text presented an unexpected output. That is, this line of text shouldn't be bolded.

Even more surprising is that, if one

- cancel the option passed to `\includegraphics`,
- or put some more text after `\textbf{}`,

the problem will go away.

I suspect the problem lies in the `FakeBold` mechanism of the `fontspec` package and/or the key-val mechanism of the `graphicx` package, but unfortunately, I don't read LaTeX3 codes, so I cannot locate it.

Maybe an issue should be posted to `fontspec` or `graphicx`, but before that, could someone provide me a quick fix to this problem?

---

**EDIT 2015/01/05**

Thanks to the help of qingkuan@bbs.ctex.org, it seems to be a bug of XeTeX. See the new MWE.

```
% !TeX program = xetex

\font\x="[cmunrm.otf]"
\font\bx="[cmunrm.otf]:embolden=5;"

\x Test
{\bx Bold Test}
\XeTeXpicfile "example-image.png"  width 1cm\relax
Words that shouldn't be bolded.


\tracingoutput=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen

\bye
```

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](https://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/005yyi5Jjw1enz43u9nnej31cq07kab7.jpg))</sub>

I made a ticket on [xetex.sf](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/105/) and hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47200/fontspec-fakebold-affects-text-in-graphics

Comment: @egreg You good memory. `: )`

Comment: Good search tools in the SE world. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

Nice test file, a workaround is to put some text after the bold text, even invisible text such as a zero width space seems to be enough:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\test[AutoFakeBold = 5]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\test
Test
\textbf{Bold Test}

\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{photo}

Words that shouldn't be bolded. Even if \textmd{textmd-ed}.

\textbf{Bold Test}^^^^200b

\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{photo}

Words that shouldn't be bolded. Even if \textmd{textmd-ed}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an answer or only pointing that there is something wrong?

Comment: @wipet it depends how soon the OP wants their document. It is certainly not the correct fix, but if someone needs the document today it may be the answer. I tried looking with \tracingall at the two versions and couldn't see any difference (although the printed output is clearly different, so I don't offer a real fix.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Yes indeed this workaround works fine, but as I posted in the question, I did know that some text after `\textbf{}` kicks the problem away, for example `\textcolor{white}{.}`. Anyway, `^^^^200b` is better. Actually, I'd uploaded my manuscript to the publisher (before your answer), so I could wait for a real fix. Thank you for this answer, and for your year after year effort on this site. `: )`

Comment: Hi David, please see my update.